# Google cardboard qr code scanner, not scanning on third party apps

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I have a poco X5 mobile and I wanna use VR apps like VRidge on it.
Inside Google Cardboard app itself, it scans immediately and finds my cardboard, but when I scan the same code in other apps like vridge 2 or any other vr app, it doesn't scan the code!
The link "Can't find this symbol?" also not working!
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8lJo.jpg)

There are no errors. Only Skip button is working!

What's the problem?!

I had used before in this mobile, and it was working fine on it's second space. But now it's not working after factory reset (on bot first and second space).

It's android 14 and updated to the last version. Google cardboard and Google vr services are installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can scan the qr code from within the Google Cardboard app instead, or update your app. Newer versions of Android may have other requirements to give access to the camera.